# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.(chrome not reachable)

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Java script (selenium framwork ) which is not running on Chrome.

I have tried all possible ways:

1. Uncheck run as admin
2. Add arguments

Code Block:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
options.setBinary("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
```

Chrome version: 108.0.5359.125

selenium-java-3.141.59

selenium-server-3.4.0

We are using web driver manager

os -win10

Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin\java.exe" -C:/Users/..../ISA/src/test/resources/Checklist/NFTE1_Confirm_login.feature
Testing started at 09:07 AM ...
inside chrome browser configuration
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71 (1e0e3868ee06e91ad636a874420e3ca3ae3756ac-refs/branch-heads/5359@{#1016}) on port 35499
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1674119263.153][WARNING]: Deprecated chrome option is ignored: useAutomationExtension
[1674119263.156][WARNING]: Deprecated chrome option is ignored: useAutomationExtension

Skipped step

Skipped step
Executed scenario successfully

Failed scenarios:
C:/Users/...../ISA/src/test/resources/Checklist/NFTE1_Confirm_login.feature:15 # Scenario Outline: Login to ISA

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
2 Steps (2 skipped)
0m20.488s

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

or you use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But not both.

Comment: i tried.. no luck....any othery way to run scripts on gogle chrome

Comment: Remove all the arguments which you don't need e.g. _`--no-sandbox`_, _`--disable-gpu`_, _`--disable-extensions`_, _`--disable-dev-shm-usage`_, _`--remote-debugging-port=9222`_, etc and take a system restart and retest.

Comment: thanks for your quick response I have removed arguments as you mentioned above.Now getting new error:                      
                                                                      
                org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '..............', ip: '11.14.208.255', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_351'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Comment: _Timed out waiting for driver server to start_: sounds like a new error all together, where as this error _`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed`_ is resolved. Feel free to raise a new ticket with all the relevant details.

Comment: Raised new ticket -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171149/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-timed-out-waiting-for-driver-server-to-s