# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, timeout

Java script (selenium framwork ) which is not running on Chrome.

I have tried all possible ways:

Uncheck run as admin

Code:

```
public void setUp() throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {
        String browser = properties.getProperty("Browser");
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.out.println("inside chrome browser configuration");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /T /F");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start Taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /T /F");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode

            System.setProperty("wdm.proxy", wdmProxy);
            System.setProperty("wdm.proxyUser", wdmProxyUser);
            System.setProperty("wdm.proxyPass", wdmProxyPwd);
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            String test = properties.getProperty("URL");
            driver.get(test);
```

Java -JDK 1.8
Chrome version: 108.0.5359.125

selenium-java-3.141.59
We are using web driver manager

os -win10

Please refer my previous fix:

[org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.(chrome not reachable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75170011/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-c)

Error:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin\java.exe" -Dorg.jetbrains.run.directory=C:\Users\............\ISA\src\test\resources\Checklist "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=56058:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\............\ISA\target\test-classes;C:\Users\............\ISA\target\classes;C:\Users\............\ISA\lib\annotations-16.0.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.5\cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-picocontainer\1.2.5\cucumber-picocontainer-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\info\cukes\gherkin\2.12.2\gherkin-2.12.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\picocontainer\picocontainer\2.15\picocontainer-2.15.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-junit\1.2.5\cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.5\cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-html\0.2.6\cucumber-html-0.2.6.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.0.5\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\masterthought\cucumber-reporting\3.19.0\cucumber-reporting-3.19.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.6\jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.6\jackson-core-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\velocity-tools\velocity-tools\1.4\velocity-tools-1.4.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.10\joda-time-2.10.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.7\commons-lang3-3.7.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\lingala\zip4j\zip4j\1.3.2\zip4j-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\3.1.0\plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.11.3\jsoup-1.11.3.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\owasp-java-html-sanitizer\owasp-java-html-sanitizer\20180219.1\owasp-java-html-sanitizer-20180219.1.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.10\commons-configuration-1.10.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\vimalselvam\cucumber-extentsreport\3.1.0\cucumber-extentsreport-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\aventstack\extentreports\3.1.5\extentreports-3.1.5.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.23\freemarker-2.3.23.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver\3.3.0\mongodb-driver-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\bson\3.3.0\bson-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-core\3.3.0\mongodb-driver-core-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.2\httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.2\httpmime-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.141.59\selenium-java-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.141.59\selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.141.59\selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.141.59\selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.141.59\selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.141.59\selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.141.59\selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.141.59\selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.141.59\selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.141.59\selenium-support-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.15\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\25.0-jre\guava-25.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.11.0\okhttp-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.14.0\okio-1.14.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-server\3.4.0\selenium-server-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.48\jcommander-1.48.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\3.2.4\cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.22\cssparser-0.9.22.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.26\htmlunit-2.26.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.26\htmlunit-core-js-2.26.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\neko-htmlunit\2.25\neko-htmlunit-2.25.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.6\httpcore-4.4.6.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0\jcip-annotations-1.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\jetty-repacked\9.4.1.v20170120\jetty-repacked-9.4.1.v20170120.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\9.4.1.v20170120\jetty-io-9.4.1.v20170120.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\9.4.1.v20170120\jetty-util-9.4.1.v20170120.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.1.0\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.1.0\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\codeborne\phantomjsdriver\1.4.0\phantomjsdriver-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\htmlunit-driver\2.26\htmlunit-driver-2.26.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-api\9.4.3.v20170317\websocket-api-9.4.3.v20170317.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-client\9.4.3.v20170317\websocket-client-9.4.3.v20170317.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-client\9.4.3.v20170317\jetty-client-9.4.3.v20170317.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\9.4.3.v20170317\jetty-http-9.4.3.v20170317.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-common\9.4.3.v20170317\websocket-common-9.4.3.v20170317.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.2\serializer-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.15\snakeyaml-1.15.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\1.8.10\pdfbox-1.8.10.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\fontbox\1.8.10\fontbox-1.8.10.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\jempbox\1.8.10\jempbox-1.8.10.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\sikuli\sikuli-api\1.2.0\sikuli-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\sikuli\sikuli-core\1.2.2\sikuli-core-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\bytedeco\javacpp\0.9\javacpp-0.9.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\bytedeco\javacpp-presets\opencv\2.4.9-0.9\opencv-2.4.9-0.9.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\piccolo2d\piccolo2d-extras\1.3.1\piccolo2d-extras-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\piccolo2d\piccolo2d-core\1.3.1\piccolo2d-core-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.6\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\net\iharder\base64\2.3.9\base64-2.3.9.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.16.0\log4j-api-2.16.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.16.0\log4j-core-2.16.0.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\io\github\bonigarcia\webdrivermanager\5.1.1\webdrivermanager-5.1.1.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java\3.2.13\docker-java-3.2.13.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java-core\3.2.13\docker-java-core-3.2.13.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java-api\3.2.13\docker-java-api-3.2.13.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.64\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.64\bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.30\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java-transport-httpclient5\3.2.13\docker-java-transport-httpclient5-3.2.13.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java-transport\3.2.13\docker-java-transport-3.2.13.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\brotli\dec\0.1.2\dec-0.1.2.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\client5\httpclient5\5.1.3\httpclient5-5.1.3.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5\5.1.3\httpcore5-5.1.3.jar;C:\Users\............\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5-h2\5.1.3\httpcore5-h2-5.1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\............\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.3\plugins\cucumber-java\lib\cucumber-jvmFormatter.jar" cucumber.api.cli.Main --plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome --glue com.rbs.CashAndCoin.commonlib --glue com.rbs.CashAndCoin.testscripts C:/Users/............/ISA/src/test/resources/Checklist/NFTE1_Confirm_login.feature
Testing started at 11:22 AM ...
inside chrome browser configuration
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
**Starting ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71** (1e0e3868ee06e91ad636a874420e3ca3ae3756ac-refs/branch-heads/5359@{#1016}) on port 20201
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
**ChromeDriver was started successfully.**
[1674127376.062][WARNING]: Deprecated chrome option is ignored: useAutomationExtension
[1674127376.062][WARNING]: Deprecated chrome option is ignored: useAutomationExtension

Skipped step

Skipped step
Executed scenario successfully

Failed scenarios:
C:/Users/............/ISA/src/test/resources/Checklist/NFTE1_Confirm_login.feature:15 # Scenario Outline: Login to ISA

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
2 Steps (2 skipped)
0m13.783s

**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)**
  **(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)**
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'GBMLVVCSW2127', ip: '11.14.208.255', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_351'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x0032F243]
    (No symbol) [0x002B7FD1]
    (No symbol) [0x001AD04D]
    (No symbol) [0x001CC24E]
    (No symbol) [0x001C82E9]
    (No symbol) [0x001FF056]
    (No symbol) [0x001FEB2A]
    (No symbol) [0x001F8386]
    (No symbol) [0x001D163C]
    (No symbol) [0x001D269D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005C9A22+2655074]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005BCA24+2601828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003D8C0A+619850]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003D7830+614768]
    (No symbol) [0x002C05FC]
    (No symbol) [0x002C5968]
    (No symbol) [0x002C5A55]
    (No symbol) [0x002D051B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x757600F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77807BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77807B8E+238]

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at com.rbs.CashAndCoin.commonlib.GenericSteps.setUp(GenericSteps.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rbs.CashAndCoin.commonlib.GenericSteps.tearDown(GenericSteps.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runAfterHooks(Runtime.java:206)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please update the question with the complete trace log of _org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)_.

Comment: _Deprecated chrome option is ignored: useAutomationExtension_: You can remove `options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);` as well.

Comment: Can you try to pass `wdmProxy`, `wdmProxyUser` and `wdmProxyPwd` through `ChromeOptions` and retest please?

Comment: Deprecated warning is gone now. but the main issue still exists.org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Comment: passed proxy, username,pwd.. still no luck

Comment: For _DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist_ error check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642913/7429447) discussion.